# Styling Wizard - remove markers but keep labeling

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have been messing around with the [google styling wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) and I am trying to remove the markers while keeping the actual labels of businesses. The goal is to remove the marker but keep the "Jimmy Johns", "Boone Saloon", "Mountaineer Mania" labels.

[image]

I have included the json I have below but it might be easiest to disregard it as a whole and start from scratch. I am new to google maps and any insight at all is appreciated more than you know!

```
{
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.attraction",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.business",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.business",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "on"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.government",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently infeasible. There is open issue regarding this matter in Google's Public Issue Tracker. You can check the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/155404710

Comment: Dang that was over a year ago… so they just aren’t fixing that. Cool. Thanks anyway